# jQuery script not loading in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse

I am trying to load a jQuery script in Eclipse and have been unable to do so. I have it stored under my WebContent folder and I believe I have the path name defined correctly, but it still doesn't seem to find the script. I am able to use the CDN successfully, but cannot seem to get it to find my `.js` file locally. Here are a couple of screenshots that will hopefully help locate my error. My project name is `DojoTest`.

[image]

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>

    <script src="WebContent/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    -->
    <script>

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
            alert( "The link will no longer take you to jquery.com" );
            //event.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Link to bigger screenshot.](https://i.imgur.com/pqHaKDd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the file relative to the current document, not your webroot, so try just

```
<script src="jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I swear this is what I did originally and it didn't work, but of course since someone else suggested it, it now works. Thanks!